# Нужна ли запятая перед тире? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Да, вы смеётесь и вам хорошо вместе, вы работаете в одной компании и у вас есть общие увлечения(,) — но что каждый из вас получает от дружбы, кроме эмоций и весёлого времяпровождения?

Comment: Помимо пунктуации, надо бы проверить семантику и стилистику. (1) "Вы получаете от дружбы эмоции" — не очень удачно. Обычно указывают, какие именно эмоции.   (2) По мнению автора общие увлечения — это всего лишь весёлое времяпровождение? Странно.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поставить тире или **запятую и тире как единый знак**. Второй вариант в ССП Лопатин считает устаревшим, а у Розенталя вообще нет информации о возможности  постановки единого знака для ССП.

В то же время  единый знак ***запятая и тире***  между смысловыми блоками в ССП (как и в других видах сложных предложений) мне кажется оправданным, так как **структура сложного предложения,  разделенного на два блока, в этом случае кажется более ясной.**

Одно тире в большей степени уместно в сложных предложениях между двумя простыми предложениями, когда оно выражает определенные отношения между ними, а не делит предложение на смысловые части.

**Да, вы смеётесь и вам хорошо вместе, вы работаете в одной компании и у вас есть общие увлечения, — но что каждый из вас получает от дружбы, кроме эмоций и весёлого времяпровождения?**

**Справочник Лопатина:** http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Примечание. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять запятая и тире как единый знак препинания: Оскалив зубы, староста стал драть его кнутом по чем попало, — и от боли и от ужаса Аверкий проснулся весь в слезах (Бун.); **На очереди были полицейские пункты, — и там о Давиде никто ничего не слыхал** (Пришв.). Такое разделение частей сложносочиненного предложения несколько устарело.

Comment: А не кажется ли вам, что здесь первая часть по смыслу является придаточной, зависимой по отношению ко второй, т.е. акцент делается именно на второй части, и тогда тире более уместно?

Comment: Тире для выражения смысловых отношений удобно использовать в сложных предложениях, состоящих из двух простых, там эти отношения  определяются достаточно конкретно. Здесь отношения между блоками выражено союзом НО. Что касается второй части,  то она по смыслу всегда зависит от первой, так как продолжает ее тему. В едином знаке, как я его понимаю, тире присоединительное, запятая обозначает границу между блоками.